# TeX code for $\lim_{x\to x_0}$

Tags: support, mathjax

I don't know how write $\lim_{x\to x_0}$ like in this page [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

I write \lim_{x\to x_0} between two `$` but the ruesult is $\lim_{x\to x_0}$.

Comment: Questions like this should be posted at tex.stackexchange.com. The meta site is only for discussion of the math.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to write `\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}`: $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}$. This works for several similar symbols: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty$, $\max\limits_{x\in X}$, etc. This is often better for inline use than `\displaystyle`, although you can always try both and see which looks best in the particular situation.

Beware that `\displaystyle` affects the rest of the LaTeX clause whereas `\limits` affects just its arguments. Furthermore, because it does not change the size of the symbols, only their placement, `\limits` usually disrupts the line spacing less than `\displaystyle`.

Compare `\displaystyle`: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$; and `\limits`: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \displaystyle: \displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} produces $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}$.